# Prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I have a proof for it. I just want to make sure it's correct.

Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that $\sqrt{2}$ is rational.

Then, $\sqrt{2} = \frac{a}{b}$ (1) , where a and b are integers and gcd(a,b)=1.

Note that $\sqrt{2}$ is non-integer. Thus, b does not divide a

Squaring both sides of equation (1),

2 = $\frac{a^2}{b^2}$. This means that $b^2|a^2$

Let p be a prime where p|$a^2$. Then $p|a$

Now assume that p| $b^2$. Then p|b. However, this is a contradiction because $gcd(a,b)= 1$

Therefore, $gcd(a^2, b^2)=1$. However, this contradicts the earlier conclusion that $b^2|a^2$

Hence, $\sqrt{2}$ cannot be rational.

Therefore, $\sqrt{2}$ irrational.

Is there something wrong with this proof?

Comment: You should make further clear why "$b^2$ divides $a^2$" is (or leads to) a contradiction. For formatting place the math expressions between dollarsigns '$'.

Comment: It is not that it is wrong wrong, but that it is incomplete. Why is it impossible for $b^2$ to divide $a^2$ while $b$ doesn't divide $a$?

Comment: "$b^2\mid a^2$ is a contradiction". You did not show that this is impossible.

Comment: just mention that the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$ is $1$ and then you're done.

Comment: @Peter Is it complete now?

Comment: @MohamedLotfi Almost. Just mention also the case $b=1$ in which we have no prime factor of $b$. If we have $b>1$, your argument applies since then $b$ must have at least one prime factor and this must also be a prime factor of $a^2$ and hence of $a$.

Comment: @Peter The argument is *not* correct because it does not correctly prove there is a prime $\,p\mid a,b,\,$ cf. "Now *assume* $p\mid b^2\ldots$" (my emph.)

Comment: @BillDubuque We have established $b^2\mid a^2$ and if $b>1$ holds , then for some prime $p$ , we must have $p\mid b$ , for this prime we also have $p\mid a^2$ and hence $p\mid a$. So where is the flaw in this argument ?

Comment: @Peter But that is not what is written above. Rather it says: "let p be a prime where p|a^2 ... Now assume p|b^2 ..."  Read it *carefully*.

Comment: @BillDubuque OK, that's a point. Thank you for pointing it out.